# thread failed to dedact callback function

Tags: c++, templates, stdthread

I have the following function:

```
    template <class T>
    void programManager(std::shared_ptr<BaseStrategy<T>> st,std::shared_ptr<SMDSSubscriber<T>> md){some code}
```

and it the callable function for std::thread

bac declare as:

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseStrategy<EZXOrderEventHandler>> bac = make_shared<BacStrategy<EZXOrderEventHandler>>
```

and md declare as:

```
std::shared_ptr<SMDSSubscriber<EZXOrderEventHandler>> dataMarket = make_shared<SMDSSubscriber<EZXOrderEventHandler>>();
   std::thread t2(&programManager,bac,dataMarket);
```

and I'm getting the error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(, std::shared_ptr >&, std::shared_ptr >&)’
>            std::thread t2(&programManager,bac,dataMarket);
>
> note: candidate: template std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
>          thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
>
> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> /home/yaodav/Desktop/git_repo/test/main.cpp:347:54: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Callable’

```
     std::thread t2(&programManager,bac,dataMarket);
```

Comment: Does `std::thread t2(programManager<EZXOrderEventHandler>,bac,dataMarket);` work?

Comment: fix the problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread::thread` requires, as its first argument, a *callable object*. `programManager` itself is not a callable object, it's a function **template**, which is basically just a generic prescription how its instances should be generated.

In your case, you need to pass a corresponding **instance** of `programManager` as an argument, which seems to be `programManager<EZXOrderEventHandler>`.